# Is there a way to get unique rows from 2 files (A anb) based on a field (let's say field3) where A takes precedence in case of duplicates?

Tags: python, bash

I have 2 files A.txt and B.txt.   I need a list of unique rows by field 2 where A.txt takes priority in case of a match with B.txt.

cat A.txt:

HHH,banana,3
HHH,apple,2
JJJ,lemon,100

cat B.txt:

LLL,pear,4
CCC,apple,9
TTT,lemon,9

The result should be:

HHH,banana,3
HHH,apple,2
JJJ,lemon,100
LLL,pear,4

Values lemon and apple repeat in both files but A.txt takes precedence.

I tried doing it in bash using gawk, sed and cut but that looked too messy.  Also, I was told that this has to be in python

No code to show.  Asking for assistance

The result should be:

HHH,banana,3
HHH,apple,2
JJJ,lemon,100
LLL,pear,4

Comment: "No code to show" is generally a problem, as this site asks for a [mcve] in your question to better guage how much you know, wht you've tried, and how best to help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk -F, '!d[$2]++' A.txt B.txt
```

This outputs:

```
HHH,banana,3
HHH,apple,2
JJJ,lemon,100
LLL,pear,4
```

Explanations:

- `-F,` tells `awk` to use `,` as a field separator
- `d` is an array that stores how many times it has *seen* a given key
- `$2` refers to the second field, which is the key you want to use to uniquely identify a row
- for each key that the script sees for the first time, `d[$2]` would be automatically evaluated as `0`
- with the not operator `!`, `!0` becomes a true value, and `awk` would perform the default action of printing the entire line
- with the `++` operator that follows `d[$2]`, `d[$2]`'s value would be incremented by `1` after its value has been evaluated
- so that the next time the script sees a line with the same key, `d[$2]` would be non-zero, and `!d[$2]` would result in a false value, and `awk` would therefore not perform any action
- `a.txt` is listd before `b.txt` so it is processed first, so its lines take precedence over those of `b.txt`

Comment: please explain this wizardry!

Comment: Glad to be of help. I've updated my answer with explanations then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read those files, split them by endOfLine and then by ",". After that, you are left with a two-dimensional list. You loop through those two lists (A is served first). then you loop through the rows. Check if not any second element of all rows of C is equal to the second element of the row of the current list. If true then append this row. Then we save the results to file C.txt.

```
def openFile(path):
    with open(path) as file:
        return file.read()
A=[i.split(',') for i in openFile('A.txt').split('\n')]
B=[i.split(',') for i in openFile('B.txt').split('\n')]
C=[]
for i in [A,B]:
    for y in i:
        if not any([y[1]==z[1] for z in C]):
            C.append(y)
with open('C.txt','w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join([','.join(i) for i in C]))
```

[image]